# Which glue works for acrylic painted slate and mdf

Tags: adhesives

I have used acrylic paint on broken used roofing slate and have tried to attach mdf cutouts with a hot glue gun and then pva glue but neither adheres.  Is there a glue which would stick the slate and mdf?

Comment: Can we assume that these are just raw materials for art that will be displayed inside, it doesn't need to hold up to weather, high humidity, or big temperature changes?  Also, give us more details on the project.  Were both the slate and MDF clean and "solid" (no surface in the process of deteriorating)?  Did you paint the parts first and then glue to the paint, or did the glue go directly on the slate and MDF?  How tightly did the surfaces mate over the whole glue joint?  How big and heavy are the components?  What kind of "abuse" does the glue need to take (cont'd)

Comment: (how strong does the bond need to be)?  How much surface area is there for the glue?  Are the pieces glued flat against each other or are you gluing pieces on end where there is a lot of potential leverage?  When the glue failed previously, did the parts just fall apart of their own weight or break apart as the result of rough handling?  When you tried the second glue, had all traces of the first glue been removed?  How long did the PVA glue dry before the pieces were handled?  (cont'd)

Comment: Without knowing any of that, what comes to mind as something that should generally work well for those two materials is to clean the surfaces well and make sure they mate well.  Then use polyurethane adhesive like Gorilla Glue.

Comment: The acrylic paint is probably causing the adhesion problem as it has sealed up the porosity the adhesive needs to grab on to. You will need to get down to the base material before you glue.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a 2 part epoxy. Like some "jb weld". They make different kinds that will stick to anything. Even some that will work underwater, others for metal, containing steel fibers. I doubt they wont have a product that will not solve your problom.